# No targets specified in the manifest when creating a Cargo workspace

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Using Rust 1.11 and Cargo 1.12 (nightly), I'm trying to create a `[workspace]` which contains a few libraries and a few executables.

In my root folder, I added my sub-crates with:

```
cargo new loader 
cargo new shell --bin
```

I then added the `cargo.toml` shown below to my root folder.

```toml
[package]
name = "rustenv"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["ME"]

[workspace]
members = [
    "loader"
    , "shell"
    ]
```

Running `cargo build` in my root folder yields:

> ```
> PS E:\r\rustenv> cargo build 
>
> error: failed to parse manifest at
> `E:\r\rustenv\Cargo.toml`
>
> Caused by:  
>  no targets specified in the manifest   
>  either src/lib.rs, src/main.rs, a [lib] section, or [[bin]] section must be  present
> ```

I am a bit confused about how this `[workspace]` feature is supposed to work given that I am a Visual Studio user by nature and there, I can simply add projects to a workspace. It appears there is something else I have to do with Cargo to get the same effect.

Answer (score 7):

If your root project does not produce any artifacts (it is not a library/binary) then in terms of the [Cargo workspaces RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1525-cargo-workspace.md)
it is "virtual", it should contain only the `workspace` section:

```toml
[workspace]
members = [
    "loader"
    , "shell"
    ]
```

If `cargo build` does not work for it, you should

```
cd loader
cargo build
cd ..
cd shell
cargo build
```

what works in such configuration? You have shared output directory "target" and "Cargo.lock", so if you type "cargo build" in "loader" subdirectory you have compiled library in "../target/"

Shell session that demonstrates how it works:

```
/tmp $ mkdir test
/tmp $ cd test
/tmp/test $ cargo new loader && cargo new shell --bin
     Created library `loader` project
     Created binary (application) `shell` project
/tmp/test $ cat > Cargo.toml
[workspace]
members = ["loader", "shell"]
/tmp/test $ cat loader/Cargo.toml 
[package]
name = "loader"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["me"]
workspace = ".."

[dependencies]
/tmp/test $ cat shell/Cargo.toml 
[package]
name = "shell"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["me"]
workspace = ".."

[dependencies]
/tmp/test/shell $ cargo build
   Compiling shell v0.1.0 (file:///tmp/test/shell)
    Finished debug [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.57 secs
evgeniy@localhost /tmp/test/shell $ ls
Cargo.toml  src
evgeniy@localhost /tmp/test/shell $ ls ../
Cargo.lock  Cargo.toml  loader  shell  target
/tmp/test $ cargo --version
cargo 0.13.0-nightly (cd8ad10 2016-08-15)
```

If you worked/work with Visual Studio, have look at [the Rust plugin for Jetbrains IDE](https://intellij-rust.github.io/)

Comment: Without the package part (and only workspace part) I get: PS E:\r\rustenv> cargo build
error: failed to parse manifest at `E:\r\rustenv\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  no targets specified in the manifest
  either src/lib.rs, src/main.rs, a [lib] section, or [[bin]] section must be present
PS E:\r\rustenv> cargo build
error: failed to parse manifest at `E:\r\rustenv\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  no `package` or `project` section found.

Comment: @BitTickler As I wrote, and as official documentation mention, **it should not work**, this is how it works now. To build you need call `cargo build` in subdirectories of real projects, not virtual.

Comment: after adding ``package.workspace`` to the sub-crates, I get: PS E:\r\rustenv\loader> cargo build
warning: unused manifest key: package.workspace

Comment: @BitTickler you should have something like `workspace = ".."` in your package sections in loader

Comment: That I have: Under ``package`` section: ``workspace = "../rustenv"``

Comment: @BitTickler If you have structure like: `rustenv/loader` and `rustenv/shell`, then you should have `workspace = ".."` in both `loader` and `shell`, not `workspace = "../rustenv"`

Comment: Tried that as well - but build of sub-crates goes to a target inside sub-crate anyway. Win64 rust version, btw.

Comment: @BitTickler I add shell session to demonstrate how it works for me.

Comment: So it is a 0.13 cargo feature? I downloaded the most recent release for my (tier 0) platform right before I started this. I expected all tier 0 platforms had the same version...